# Caesar cipher and handling non-letter characters

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I'm trying implement Caesar cipher in Python 2.7 and have a problem with characters such as comma, colon, etc. The problem is I want to keep them unchanged after text encryption, but for some reason function "encrypt_plaintext" outputs number of characters without spaces or any non letters signs. I've tried concatenation but no luck; same as ".join" method.
I would appreciate for any suggestions.

```
import sys


plain = open('plain.txt')
try:
    plaintext = plain.read()
finally:
    plain.close()


decrypt = open('decrypt.txt')
try:
    decrypttext = decrypt.read()
finally:
    decrypt.close()


crypto = open('crypto.txt')
try:
    cryptotext = crypto.read()
finally:
    crypto.close()


key = open('key.txt')
try:
    keytext = key.read()
finally:
    key.close()


for cezarkey in keytext[0]:
    print cezarkey


def encrypt_plaintext(x):
    crypt = ''
    for i in x:
        if i>='a' and i<='z' or i>='A' and i<='Z':
            crypt += chr(ord(i)+int(cezarkey)%26)
        else:
            i+(crypt)

    print "The decrypted message is: " + crypt
    #crypto = open('crypto.txt', 'w')
    #crypto.write(crypt)
    #crypto.close()

#szyfr = [ chr(ord(c)+k%26) if c>='a' and c<='z' or c>='A' and c<='Z' else c for c in tekst ]
#print ''.join(szyfr)


def decrypt_cyphertext(x):
    crypt = ""
    for i in x:
        crypt += chr((((ord(i) - 97) - int(cezarkey)) % 26) + 97)
    print "The decrypted message is: " + crypt
    decrypt = open('decrypt.txt', 'w')
    decrypt.write(crypt)
    decrypt.close()


if sys.argv[1:3] == ['-c', '-e']:
    encrypt_plaintext(plaintext)

elif sys.argv[1:3] == ['-c','-d']:
    decrypt_cyphertext(cryptotext)
```

Comment: `i+(crypt)` this does nothing (rather, it does something but discards the result)

Comment: Please note that your script is hardly an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There is a lot of material in the question that is not really relevant to the problem.  (You could provide literal strings instead of reading values from files, for example.)

Comment: I agree with you Jonathan, unfortunately requirements are different, plain text and key must be loaded from a file.

Comment: @dimon> his point was, when posting on SO, you should change your program to extract the problem as a minimal example (a MCVE, see his link). Your question should not be about solving your whole program, but solving a specific, focused issue. All the rest should be removed or replaced with dummy data.

Comment: Right, I've got it now, sorry guys I'm newbie here :)